# Join a table with dates with a table with date spans

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables I want to join. One is a logging table that records events on a certain time. The other is a session table. I want to find out which event happened in which session.

The event table has a `timestamp` field of type `timestamp(0) without time zone`, and the session table has a `logintime` and `logouttime` of type `timestamp without time zone` (`userid` is a field that is available in both tables).

The SQL I tried is this:

```
 select S.sessionid from event E
 left join session S 
 ON S.logintime =
 (
    select MAX(logintime) max
    from session
    where (
           (logintime < E.timestamp and logouttime > E.timestamp) OR
           (logintime < E.timestamp AND logouttime is null)
          ) and S.userid=E.userid
 )
```

When users are logged out, the session is found fine, but when `logouttime` is `NULL`, the join fails and I get no `sessionid`. When I do all the subqueries manually, they seem to yield correct results.

Example of the latter:

First, we take a random event record.

```
select * from event limit 1;
      timestamp      | userid | ....
---------------------+--------+-----
 2014-07-15 15:44:24 |    195 | ....
```

Second, we take the join clause, filled in with received data

```
select MAX(logintime) max from session 
where ((logintime <'2014-07-15 15:44:24' and logouttime > '2014-07-15 15:44:24') OR
       (logintime < '2014-07-15 15:44:24'  AND logouttime is null)) and userid=195;

            max             
----------------------------
 2014-07-15 12:18:03.648875
```

And finally, We take the sessionid that matches that time.

```
select * from session where logintime='2014-07-15 12:18:03.648875';
              sessionid               | userid |         logintime          | logouttime 
--------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------+------------
 4e56b28a-0c09-11e4-af0d-5b9f3f52ff0d |    195 | 2014-07-15 12:18:03.648875 |
```

Comment: PostgreSQL version? (you can add as a tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.2+, you can use the timestamp range [`tsrange`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) to detect [containment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html):

```
select s.sessionid
from event e
left join session s on s.userid = e.userid
  and tsrange(logintime, logouttime) @> E.timestamp
```

**Note**: ranges can be [unbounded](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE), so you didn't have to specify another case for `logouttime IS NULL`.

**Edit**: if one user can have multiple sessions at a specific time (and you want to select only the one with the last `logintime`), you can use the [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause:

```
select distinct on(s.sessionid) s.sessionid
from event e
left join session s on s.userid = e.userid
  and tsrange(logintime, logouttime) @> E.timestamp
order by s.sessionid, logintime desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the `tsrange`, it works better now, but I also get joins for "open" sessions in the past (there can be multiple open sessions, I need to join on the last, hence my `MAX` part).